# lnd Command not found after installing from source

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, compiling, installation

I want to run a lightning node. I already have bitcoin full node on a raspberry pi 4 external hard drive and I installed lnd on the hard drive like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd
cd lnd
make install
```

Executing the command: lnd

```
lnd: command not found
```

```
echo $GOPATH
/home/my-name/go
```

My .bashrc

```
export GOPATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

```
echo $PATH
:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Installing process gave no error.
Where would the lnd be?

The question is asked already but not helpful for me. I already did it

```
find /usr/local -name lnd
/usr/local/go/bin/lnd
/usr/local/go/bin/lnd/lnd
```

find /home/myname -name lnd gives back nothing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lnd` is not in your `$PATH` you need to update your .bashrc file, add those lines to it

```
export GOPATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

then after saving your changes reload the file with `source ~/.bashrc` now it should work, if not you can still run it directly with its full path `/usr/local/go/bin/lnd`

If you want to install on what I suppose is an external do that:

lets assume your external hard drive is mounted on `/mnt/external_hd` first lets go to it `cd /mnt/external_hd/lnd` then build `lnd` and `lncli` `make && make install` then update your bashrc export

```
GOPATH=/mnt/external_hd/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

then we load bashrc `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: No its not working. /usr/local/local/go/bin and then lnd says lnd is a directory. when I go cd lnd I have: cert, healthcheck, lnd, ticker, tor, clock, kvdb, queue and tlv. lnd is a directory again. cd lnd again and there are the same folder inside but not a lnd folder again. Probably I made something wrong but lnd command is not working there as well

Comment: Maybe I found it. after redoing everything inside of the external hard drive in ..../lnd/cmd I have the folder lncli and lnd. In lnd there is a main.go and in lncli are a lot .go files. Is this the location I need?

Comment: Installing LND on the SD Card works perfectly. Then everything works. but what do I have to do to install it from the mnt/ ?

Comment: I updated my answer for when you want to install it from the mnt/